# divs not expanding 100%, also feedback please

Tags: css, html, feedback

New to HTML/CSS (1-2 months).

When I make the browser smaller the circles keep pushing through but the parent divs wont follow to 100% of the width.

As seen in photo:
http://i1239.photobucket.com/albums/ff515/Cyrixau/eg_zps35c7b645.png

How can I fix this?

HTML and CSS can be seen in the site here:
http://fsd.netii.net/

Also, I'm interested in becoming a front end developer, the way I'm structuring my html/css, the way I position everything. Is this best practice? Could I please get feedback on what I can improve on.

Thanks.

Comment: Post the relevant code here, not some external sites.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you specify fix widths for your `.header-circles` and `.a-circle` classes in your CSS.

Try using media queries and resizing the classes when the browser width gets smaller.

```
@media (max-width: 1140px) {
  .header-circles {
    width:100%;
  }
  .a-circle{
    width:130px;
    height:130px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .a-circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
}
```

I haven't tested that but that would be the idea

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making a responsive website and you are using a lot of fixed widths in your css. You should have percentages instead of pixels.

You don't need absolute positioning of elements, and you could place your elements style on the class instead of each element.

And you should use media queries to do responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you are absolutely positioning the circle elements:

```
#cirle1 { 
    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
}
#cirle2 { 
    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 285px; 
}
#cirle3 { 
    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 570px; 
}
```

...

There are two things you can do to get effect your are trying to achieve, either way you need to remove the absolute positioning on the circle containers and set the max widths of the parent divs to 100%.

```
#circles-content, .header-circles { 
  width: 100%; max-width: 100%; 
}
```

**And then you can either**

Float the circle containers:

```
.circle-container: { 
    float: left; margin-left: 5%;
}
```

Set their display property to inline-block:

```
.circle-container: { 
    display:inline-block; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you are asking how to make your HTML elements "responsive" when then browser's width changes. If this is the case, there are two ways to do this.

First, fluid layout: you need to use percentage as the measurement unit to layout your elements. Since you are using pixel, try changing it into percentage -- something like this:

```
/* SLIDER */
#slider-container {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;  
}

/* BODY */
#circles-content {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 285px;
}

.header-circles { 
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}

.circle-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 285px;
}

.a-circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 55px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    border: 2px solid #3498db;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

#circle-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 20%;
}

#circle-3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 40%;
}

#circle-4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 60%;
}
```

Second, responsive design. This is somewhat more advanced than fluid layout. The main idea is the write different CSS for different browser's dimensions so that you can correctly layout your HTML elements in multiple dimensions. Google the terms and comparisons between them. You need to research a bit on it to understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

remove all ID from your circles and ID styles too:

```
<div class="header-circles">
    <div class="circle-container">...</div>
    <div class="circle-container">...</div>
    <div class="circle-container">...</div>
    <div class="circle-container">...</div>
</div>
```

edit `.circle-container` like this:

```
.circle-container {
width: 285px;
height: 285px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

change `.a-circle` position to relative:

```
.a-circle {
position: relative;   /*  <<--- changed  */
top: 35px;
left: 55px;
padding-left: 50px;
width: 175px;
height: 175px;
border: 2px solid #3498db;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 16px rgba(255,255,255,0.6), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

edit `.header-circles` and `#circles-content` like this:

```
.header-circles {
position: relative;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
}

#circles-content {
background-color: #F0F0F0;
width: 100%;
}
```

**DONE**